# Broadcast to locations within 15 mile radius

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I'm really not sure which method is best, but I need to be able to broadcast to a user-base located within 15 miles of N.

So, if `userA` needs to report to the member base that they've lost their pet, the system will send out emails to those members located within a 15 mile radius of `userA`

I'd love to utilize Google Maps, and longitude and latitude ... I have `userA`s Postal/ZIP code, so perhaps I can use that to lookup it's longitude and latitude and then do the broadcast.

---

My question is this: if I have the ZIP / Postal Code for `userA`, how do I utilize the Google Maps API to then broadcast to all over users that have a ZIP / Postal Code within 15 miles of `userA` ... I don't need to know what the SQL query needs to be ... I just need to know how to utilize the Google API ... what paramaters are required, etc.

Comment: so what is your question? how do do the distance search to know who to email? and what would the role of the map? would that be within the email body?

Comment: Your question still isn't very clear.  The Google Maps API has nothing to do with sending messages to people.  Do you need to know how to geocode?  What specifically are you having trouble with.

Comment: I'm afraid a postal code isn't accurate enough

Comment: @Brad, ignore the email functionality ... that has nothing to do with the question. That's just extra information.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, that's not true. http://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm

Comment: Alright, so by broadcast you mean e-mail, and that has nothing to do with your question and is extra information.  Then what is your question?  "if I have the ZIP / Postal Code for userA, how do I utilize the Google Maps API to then broadcast to all over users that have a ZIP / Postal Code within 15 miles of userA"  Again, is your question about geocoding?  How to query for coordinate pairs within a distance?

Comment: @dcolumbus: The linked page starts with a point, not with a ZIP-code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Google geocoding API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

you could call it with `file_get_contents`, and then `json_decode` the response...

and here's a sample call:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=60201&sensor=false

but if you look at the response you get, you're going to get a bounding box (and central point) for the ZIP...so you have to decide how you want to define your search range...if some hypothetical ZIP is 15 miles in each dimension, would you just message users within that ZIP? And, if the ZIP is 100 miles in each dimension, you won't be able to tell the users within 15 miles from those much further out.

You could say "everyone in my zip code, as well as those zip codes that have any portion within 15 miles of this zip code's perimeter"...but if you have two very large zip codes touching, you're going to be hitting a huge area.

Have you looked at [navigator.geolocation](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/)? Or considered incorporating some other data gathering option like a mobile application that reports users locations to your system? Or, for that matter, just letting them input more than a ZIP...why not full address?